# secp256k1 generated private keys

Tags: wallets

I have a question on the generated key pair (public, private) using secp256k1. Because this is the same curve and params used for both bitcoin and Ethereum.

Does that technically mean, once you have a pair, you technically have access to three wallets (if you wanted to) one in Tezos, in Ethereum and in Bitcoin ?

Also does that mean I would use the same BIP-32 standard to generate HD Wallets for Tezos also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to use [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki). For C# you can use [Netezos](https://netezos.dev/docs/wallet-import.html)

Comment: what about the  generated keys using secp256k1 can the pair generated technically be used for all the blockchain that use this type of curve / configuration ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same private key bytes.